# How does Kaldi compare with Mozilla DeepSpeech in terms of speech recognition accuracy?

Tags: speech-recognition

How does [Kaldi ASR](https://kaldi-asr.org/) compare with [Mozilla DeepSpeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech) in terms of the speech recognition accuracy (e.g., in terms of [word error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_error_rate))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://web.archive.org/web/20171130080859/https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/11/a-journey-to-10-word-error-rate/ :

> Our **word error rate on LibriSpeech’s test-clean set is 6.5%**, which not only achieves our initial goal, but gets us close to human level performance. [...] (5.83% according to the Deep Speech 2 paper).  On a MacBook Pro, using the GPU, the model can do inference at a real-time factor of around 0.3x, and around 1.4x on the CPU alone. (A real-time factor of 1x means you can transcribe 1 second of audio in 1 second.)

Bonus:  [Facebook AI Research Automatic Speech Recognition Toolkit](https://github.com/facebookresearch/wav2letter) (Torch+lua, BSD License) gets 4.8% WER test-clean and 14.5% WER test-other on the  LibriSpeech corpus.

Comment: Since you found the answer, you could mark your own answer as "accepted". Otherwise, the question will keep getting bumped to the front page by SE bots.

Comment: @prash Good point, done

Comment: WER is not the only parameter we should be measuring how one ASR library fares against the other, a few other parameters can be: how good they fare in noisy scenarios, how easy is it to add vocabulary, what is the real-time factor, how robustly the trained model responds to changes in accent intonation etc.

Comment: @AbSin 100% agreed.

Answer (score 3):

Kaldi provides WER of 4.28% whereas deepspeech gives 5.83% on librispeech clean data. Check this out: https://github.com/syhw/wer_are_we

Comment: Thanks, it's not Mozilla DeepSpeech though, but Baidu's :/